# UV filter, does it exist?

Tags: visible-light

On the video here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9BqrSAHbTc, Thomas Leveritt uses a UV filter which, as far as I understand, lets only the UV through.

I couldn't find any photo filter that do that. There exist UV cameras or anti-UV filters but I can't find such a UV filter.

Do I understand well ? Do such UV filter exists ?

Comment: Have a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraviolet_photography#Reflected_UV_photography); remember most types of glass are strong absorbers of UV so you need to look to make your equipment out of something else (e.g. quartz).

Comment: try http://photo.stackexchange.com/ and call it a UV pass filter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you are getting it wrong! UV filter , Will "Filter" the Ultra violet light. it means no ultra violet can get trough it. it is very cheap and you can find a UV filter every where. almost every camera has a UV filter to prevent ultra violet light to get through the lens.

and also there are filters that will pass only ultra violet lights, as they absorb other light waves other than UV (Other normal wavelength, not X Ray for example)

EDIT: I saw the Video,Yes it is "UV Pass Filter" it only let the UV light pass the filter. and some processes are made inside the camera so the light (or better called information) is turned into black and white color because we can't **SEE** UV lights.and  because of the shorter wave length of UV, we can see more information and details by absorbing data from UV light reflected from skins.

Comment: If you looked at the video in the link, it specifically talks about a camera that looks at the UV content of the image. In your first line you say "No" (presumably to the question "do such UV filters exist"), and then you say they do exist. I don't see how your answer addresses the question - maybe it needs a bit of editing?

Comment: @Floris by no I meant, "NO" you are getting it wrong. I haven't see the video. I'll check it out and tell you the result.

Comment: I think it is OK to say "such UV filter" as in "when I have a filter that only lets through UV, and I want to call that a UV filter, that's not a bad name for it". OP clearly recognizes that this is not a "conventional" UV filter you can buy at any camera dealer (the kind he calls "anti-UV filter").

Comment: @Floris I saw the Video,Yes it is "UV Pass Filter" it only let the UV light pass the filter. and some processes are made inside the camera so the light (or information) is turn into black and white color because we can't SEE UV lights. because of the shorter wave length of UV, we can see more information by absorbing data from UV light reflected from skins.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the right name of such a filter : "UV Pass Filter"

Answer (score 0):

They certainly do exist, but you might have trouble finding one mounted for compatibility  with a camera whose sensitivity is in the visible region.  One example is [Schott UG5](http://www.us.schott.com/advanced_optics/english/products/filteroverviewdetail-bandpass-uv.html).

Comment: Indeed it is not enough to have a filter that blocks the visible light - you need a sensor that detects what's left. I suspect that most digital cameras have a sensor that can do this - the question is whether the optics in front (the lens) lets enough of the UV through (most optics is coated with an anti-UV coating to prevent hazing of the image).

Answer (score 0):

UV filters for photography filter out near-blue uv light. They were commonly used when film was still popular as many films were sensitive to these wavelengths and, without a filter, the result was a bluish tinge to the pictures. Digital sensors don't have this issue so uv filters are far less common nowadays. Hence when they are used with digital cameras, all they end up doing is protecting the lens' glass (but possibly also adding to lens flare issues).

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=ahOo1r78sB8